# May I dual-wield unarmed strikes with Scarlet Throne?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

According to the d20pfsrd, "All Scarlet Throne maneuvers and stances require that ... He must either have his off-hand empty, or be wielding a weapon two-handed to use this discipline."

If I use a Scarlet Throne manoeuvre that allows me to make a full-attack, may I make an attack with my off-hand as long as that off-hand attack is an unarmed strike (and thus my off-hand remains empty)?

Alternatively, may I make a normal full-attack and include an unarmed strike with my off-hand while in a Scarlet Throne stance without forfeiting its benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Ive carefully looked at Scarlet Throne and was unable to come across any rules which would prevent you from using your offhand when empty to attack with, so even TWF could be allowed, when your offhand is empty.

But in reality it should be ruled on by whoever is running your game. Personally I dont see any great bonus in attacking with your hand, but it would hurt all your attacks in the round.

Comment: I've decided to accept this interpretation as RAW, with the caveat that I probably wouldn't allow it as GM.

The reason I would want to attack with my offhand in an unarmed strike is that I have an unarmed-strike improving class feature (meditant psychic warrior) and will later gain a flurry-like class feature.